# PHP to extract specific words

Tags: php

I have a string like the below in a variable called $CPU. The text is below, my target is to pull specific element of the below text.

```
[{
  "@attributes": {
    "name": "processors"
  },
  "entry": ["2", "1", "successful"],
  "entries": {
    "@attributes": {
      "name": "processor"
    },
    "entry": ["Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz", "GenuineIntel", "2500000000", "3100000000", "2", "4", "true", "9", "100 MHz", "7"],
    "entries": {
      "@attributes": {
        "name": "caches"
      },
      "entries": [{
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 1 Cache", "131072"]
      }, {
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 2 Cache", "524288"]
      }, {
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 3 Cache", "3145728"]
      }]
    }
  }
}]
```

The thing I want to extract specifically is this bit is the "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz" however I'm really unsure how to achieve this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a JSON! So if it works for JS it will work for PHP:

```
$arr = json_decode($CPU, true);
echo $arr[0]["entries"]["entry"][0];
```

```js
var x = [{
  "@attributes": {
    "name": "processors"
  },
  "entry": ["2", "1", "successful"],
  "entries": {
    "@attributes": {
      "name": "processor"
    },
    "entry": ["Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz", "GenuineIntel", "2500000000", "3100000000", "2", "4", "true", "9", "100 MHz", "7"],
    "entries": {
      "@attributes": {
        "name": "caches"
      },
      "entries": [{
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 1 Cache", "131072"]
      }, {
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 2 Cache", "524288"]
      }, {
        "@attributes": {
          "name": "cache"
        },
        "entry": ["Level 3 Cache", "3145728"]
      }]
    }
  }
}]

console.log(x[0]["entries"]["entry"][0])
```

Comment: Thankyou! I've added the above code but I get an error now saying cannot use object of type stdclass